# uninstall dropbox on android HTC

Tags: android, dropbox, uninstallation

I have a HTC with htc sence and android.
Dropbox was automatically installed on my phone but I don't need it, I use drive.
How can I uninstall it?

Comment: It's not exactly a programming question... And a quick answer - without access to root, you can't remove preinstalled apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, HTC have baked it into the OS as an OS Level Installation. It can be removed, but you need to root your device and remove manually. Personally, I wouldn't recommend it unless you understand how to do it.

Comment: I agree Ruben, I switched from my HTC Sensation XE to a Google Galaxy Nexus for that exact reason. For me it was Facebook that drove me away.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the new HTC series (One X, One V, etc.)

DropBox comes packed with the OS, so you can't remove it without rooting your phone.